# Azure bicep dependsOn for existing resource

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

From my "main" bicep module, I would like to reference an existing function that is created by a module called from the same "main" bicep. So used the following code:

```
resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' existing = {
  name: functionAppName
  scope: resourceGroup(subscriptionId, 'rg-365response-${env}-001')
}
```

I am then able to use properties from the "functionApp" resource variable to obtain the function key and store as a key vault secret as follows:

```
resource funcSecret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2021-04-01-preview' = {
  name: '${kvName}/funcAppKey'
  properties: {
    value: listKeys('${functionApp.id}/host/default', functionApp.apiVersion).functionKeys.default
  }
}
```

However, when I run a resource group deployment and see the following error:

> The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/func-365response-int-001' under
> resource group 'rg-365response-int-001' was not found

This is some kind of timing issue, I guess it's checking for the function app before the call to the module that creates it has had chance to complete.

If I run the "main" bicep module a second time, everything works okay.

It seems it's not possible to use the "dependsOn" syntax for a resource that is "existing".

Is there an alternative?

Comment: could you share a little bit more ? what are you trying to do with the function reference ? You could always have another module that will encapsulate the logic you are after.

Comment: @Thomas please find additional info added to the post

Comment: you could always wrap that inside it own module so you wont have any reference issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DependOns` can only be used for resources defined in the same bicep file (ARM template).
When you use the `existing` keyword, it will compiled to a `resourceId() or reference()` by Bicep

You could create a module to create secret:

```bicep
// key-vault-secret.bicep

param kvName string
param secretName string
@secure()
param secretValue string

resource kv 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: kvName
}

resource kvSecret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2023-02-01' = {
  name: secretName
  parent: kv
  properties: {
    value: secretValue
  }
}
```

Then from where you are creating your function, you could invoke it like that:

```bicep
resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-03-01' = {
  name: functionAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  ...
}

// Add secret to KV
module functionKey 'key-vault-secret.bicep' = {
  name: 'function-default-host-key'
  scope: resourceGroup()
  params:{
    kvName: kvName
    secretName: 'funcAppKey'
    secretValue: listKeys('${functionApp.id}/host/default', functionApp.apiVersion).functionKeys.default
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct in that the listKeys() is called too early, you can't fix it with dependsOn unfortunately.  There is a bit more explanation here: https://bmoore-msft.blog/2020/07/26/resource-not-found-dependson-is-not-working/

The only fix for this is to put the listKeys and the function into different modules and make sure you have dependsOs if the second module doesn't consume an input from the first.

The part that's not adding up for me is that you have an `existing` keyword on the resource in the sample above but you say you're creating it.  The symptoms you describe also suggest you're creating it in the same deployment.  If you are, they you don't need the `existing' keyword.

If all else fails - post all the code.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The function app is created by a dedicated bicep module that is called from "main". I need to get hold of the functionApp.id and functionApp.apiVersion so I can call listKeys. That's why I'm making use of the existing keyword. I've copied the relevant parts of main and the function app module here: https://github.com/RobBowman/stack-overflow/tree/main

Comment: I've added a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73232751/azure-bicep-referencing-a-variable-that-cannot-be-calculated-at-the-start

Comment: Got it - the simplest solution is to put the `existing` resource and the `secrets` creation into a new module.  Make that module dependent on the first.  Will take a look at the related.